# Network unclaimed - 14.04 not loading the right drivers after freeze and hard shutdown

Tags: networking, drivers

While I was surfing using Chrome, Ubuntu froze up and I had to hard shutdown my notebook.

After the reboot wireless, Ethernet, audio and also my wireless mouse are not working any more. The screen resolution is locked on 1024 x768.

`lswh -C network` says for `eth` and `wireless`  `*-network unclaimed`

I think it's a driver problem.

How do I get back to my old drivers configuration without an internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved running this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic
```

After reboot everything was as before

Comment: how did you manage to do that without an internet connection?